# Asking for a hint to prove that altitudes of a triangle meet in a point.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, solution-verification

**Problem**: Use cyclic quadrilaterals to give another
proof that altitudes of a triangle meet in a point, as follows. Let
$ABC$ be the given triangle. Let the altitudes $BL$ and $CK$ meet at $H$. Let $AH$
meet the opposite side at $M$. Then show
that $AM \perp BC$.

**Attempt**: [All that I did is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sdi2t.png), I drew $KL$, and found that the two polygons colored in Red and Black are cyclic. I just need a hint to continue on my own.

Comment: Is it necessary to include cyclic quadrilateral in the proof. This can be easily proved by coordinate geometry..

Comment: I know it can, and I also know it can be proved by showing the altitudes of an arbitrary triangle are the perpendicular bisectors of another, but it is necessary to use cyclic quadrilaterals in this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I've verified that the angles can be labelled angles can be deduced.)

You are very close. Find more cyclic quads via angle chasing.

Obvious hint (IE This is a natural step when problem solving):
 Assuming that $AM$ was truly an altitude, we know that $ALMB$ is a cyclic quad.
So, can you prove that $ALMB$ is a cyclic quad without the assumption?
If yes, we should likely be able to backtrack the steps and conclude that $AM$ is an altitude.

> you have $\angle LAM = \angle LBM = \alpha$,

$ $

> so $ ALMB$ is a cyclic quad,

$ $

> so $\angle AMB = \angle ALB = 90^ \circ $.

Comment: Thanks, this was really helpful.
But just to confirm, I proved that ALMB is cyclic as your hint suggested, and I discovered that since $\angle LAM = \angle LBM$, it's indeed cyclic.
Then in triangle KHB, $\angle KBH = 90 - (\alpha + \beta)$, and this angle is equal to $\angle LMH$, so it follows that $\angle AMB = 90$ and thus $AM \perp BC$

Comment: Yup, that works. The idea behind the "obvious hint" is a good way to discover possible approaches. It can be a good way to guide wishful thinking / intuition, though it might not always work (e.g. if an equation has multiple solutions).